# Registry permission in Windows

Tags: windows, winapi, registry, uac

In my small application I am trying to create a sub-key in registry. I am doing this in Windows 7. I've tried all the possible combinations of keys for the `RegCreateKeyEx` function. As I remember, in Win XP everything was fine. Nevertheless it returns me always "*Access denied*" result. I have found that one must to do something with *User Access Control* settings. This information is explained in a chaotic manner and I haven't got what should be done. Can someone show me the way out? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post a minimal amount of code that we can compile and check?

Comment: Start with running your app "As Administrator" to see is that was UAC preventing you from doing something restricted. Then updating your question with relevant info would be great.

Comment: Which key are you trying to open? What rights are you asking for? Write access?

Comment: @David Heffernan I am doing that for HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT

Comment: @RomanR. Good suggestion. Will write later.

Comment: And are you trying to write under that key?

Comment: Yeap, I am trying to create a new entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the comments, you are trying to write to HKCR. In order to do that you need admin rights.

1. On XP your user is an administrator and so has admin rights. The code succeeds.
2. On Vista and up, with UAC active, your user, even if an admin user, runs with a standard user token. The code fails with access denied.

If you really do need to write to this key then you are going to need to run with administrator rights. That's going to require a requireAdministrator manifest.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is don't try to write priviledged keys. For instance, use `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` as root instead of `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`.

Comment: Writing to HKCU doesn't help if the key you need is in HKCR